# oracle Forms error FRM-40654

Tags: forms, oracle

When I update a table through a data block, I am getting an error in the parent form "FRM-40654 Record has been updated by another user.Re-query to see change". I have looked into Oracle forums and tried the changes in properties. There are no triggers also. It Forms 6i. How can I trace where exactly the error is happening in the form? I tried to enable the database trace within the form load. But it is not creating trace file. I am opening a data block from the form on a button click. How can I refresh the form with latest data when I comeback from the datablock?

Answer (score 1):

it's been awhile since I used Oracle forms but I believe you can deal with this by wrapping your update in a package.  Then from the trigger that initiates the save create a Declare Begin Exception End block to catch the FRM-40654.

When this event is caught in the exception block try requerying then updating the information by calling the packaged procedure again.